# Execute a code after every function is called

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a `scrolltobottom()` function that is run after every function is executed.

How can I refactor the code so that I don't need to type `scrolltobottom()` everywhere?

Preferably without using Jquery.

```
async function initBot () {
  let botui = BotUI('homepage-bot', {
    vue: Vue
  })

  let scrolltobottom = () => {
    let ele = document.getElementById('botui')
    document.body.scrollTop = ele.clientHeight
  }

  await botui.message.bot({"Hello"})
  await scrolltobottom()

  await botui.message.bot({"Do you like apple or orange?"})
  await scrolltobottom()

  await botui.message.button({"Orange", "Apple"})
  await scrolltobottom()
}
```

Comment: if all of the other functions were `botui.message.bot` rather than a mixture of `botui.message.bot` and `botui.message.button` - then you'd simply put the `scrolltobottom` in `botui.message.bot`

Comment: why are you `await`ing a synchronous function?

Answer (score 4):

You could create a decorator function

```
function decorateWith(targetFn, fn){
  return function(){
    targetFn.apply(this, arguments);
    fn();
  }
}

[ botui.message.bot,
  botui.message.button ]
  .forEach(fn => decorateWith(fn, scrolltobottom));
```